# Mahapps ShowProgressBarAsync only shows after my loading task is finished

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to use the mahaps progress bar dialog for my application to trigger when a task starts that would normally freeze the application for a few seconds.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingDialog();

    SaveAndLoadData.SaveUserData(ApplicationData.UserData);
    MainWindowLogic.LogIntoWebsites();
}

private async void LoadingDialog()
{
    var controller = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Logging In...", "");
}
```

The Loading dialog doesn't actually pop up till after my `LogIntoWebsites()` method has finished. I'm getting a feeling that I am not understanding asynchronous right, and that I'm definitely doing something wrong here.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `LoadingDialog` in a "fire and forget" style of execution. I'm not sure that's what you want to do.

If you want the dialog to appear before `LogIntoWebsites`, you'll need to change the methods signature from `async void` to `async Task`, and asynchronously wait on it using `await`:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await LoadingDialogAsync();

    SaveAndLoadData.SaveUserData(ApplicationData.UserData);
    MainWindowLogic.LogIntoWebsites();
}

private async Task LoadingDialogAsync()
{
    var controller = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Logging In...", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval! Makes sense. However after doing this the "overlay" for the dialog box will come across the screen, but the dialog box itself does not actually come up till my loading task is complete still. I'm wondering if there is another issue present.

Comment: What is your "loading task"? And who is responsible for showing the dialog?

Comment: The "loading task" is saving the user data and starting up a WebDriver and logging into some websites. As soon as the WebDriver has loaded the loading dialog shows up. 

Right now The codebehind on the window (this doesn't follow MVVM) is responsible for showing the dialog, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Are these other operation asynchronous as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Mahaps progress bar, but if you want to keep your UI responsive using the async-await pattern you should declare your event handler async.

> The event handler is the only async function that can return a void and doesn't have to return a Task or a Task`<TResult`>

From within this async event handler you don't have to create new tasks. Just call normal functions and as soon as you think a function might take some time, declare the function async and await for the timely action.

Your event handler calls three functions. I don't know which ones take long time to execute. So let's assume only the first one is relatively slow. The code would look like follows:

```
private **async** void Button_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    await LoadingDialog();
    SaveAndLoadData.SaveUserData(ApplicationData.UserData);
    MainWindowLogic.LogIntoWebsites();
}

private async void LoadingDialog()
{
    var controller = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Logging In...", "");
}
```

If SaveUserData and LogIntoWebsites are also fairly slow, consider creating async versions for them. If they can call async functions, then the async version is fairly easy. If not you'll have to create a task yourself and wait for them. Example:

```
private async void LogIntoWebSitesAsync()
{
    // do some processing
    // if possible call other async functions
    await OtherFunctionAsync(); // use this if return value is Task
    TResult result = await YetAnotherAsync(); // use if return Task`<TResult`>
    // here you can use result

    // or if you want some parallel processing:
    var taskA = YetAnotherAsync();
    // while taskA is performing, do other things
    // after a while you need the result:
    TResult taskAResult = await taskA;

    // or even start several tasks:
    var taskX = functionXAsync(...);
    var taskY = functionYAsync(...);
    // do some more processing, and after a while you need the results:
    await Task.WhenAll( new Task[] {taskX, taskY});
    var Xresult = taskX.Result;
    var Yresult = taskY.Result;
    ProcessResults(XResult, YResult);
}
```

If your event handler needs to call a long function that doesn't have an sync version, create a task for it and await for it:

```
private TResult LongFunction()
{
    // do something slow
    TResult result = ...;
    return result;
}

private async Task`<TResult`> LongFunctionAsync(...)
{
    // do some processing
    // start the task
    var longTask = Task.Run( () => LongFunction(...);
    // while longTask running, do some more processing
    // when the result is needed:
    TResult result = await longTask;

    // or if you don't have anything else to do you can await immediately
    await Task.Run ( () => {...} );
    return result;
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    TResult result = await LongFunctionAsync(...);
    ProcessResult(result);
}
```